# Not able to Register initBinder on Interceptor class

Tags: spring-mvc, binding

I'm trying to register `initBinder` on `Interceptor` class but I'm unable to do so.

This is my code:

```java
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    final String mysqlDatePattern = this.messageSource.getMessage("calendar.format", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
    final String javaDatePattern = StringReplaceUtils.mysqlToJavaDatePattern(mysqlDatePattern);     
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat(javaDatePattern, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()), true));    
}
}
```

Comment: Can you give the Interceptor details?

Comment: Interceptor creates a Model object , passes to the Model and returns the Model by overriding the postHandle(){; method by

Comment: using modelandView.addobject("objectname", Object);

Comment: Is that interceptor `implements HandlerInterceptor ` ? You can use `@InitBinder` in your controller.

Comment: Yes the Interceptor implements HandlerInterceptor .

Comment: here the problem is there are 2 models returned on the same page. One is the base model that returns dynamic pages and other is the model that loads a constant only when we hover on a button(kind off preference pages that allows users to choose no of table row entries he wants to see on the main pages etc etc).

Comment: I have used @initBinder on the controller of the pages which are loaded dynamically but the page returned by interceptor class(preference page) does provides register to bind

Comment: Need help how can we register binder on interceptor

Comment: As far as i know, you can not register `initBinder` to `HandlerInterceptor`. Logically it can not be. Because `HandlerInterceptor` is common place for all requests and it intercept request before the request converted as objects or beans. Beans, objects are created in between Controller and interceptor layer. But `InitBinder` as well as `WebDataBinder` provide validator for beans or objects. So logically you can not get it. Why do you need it in `HandlerInterceptor `? If you need a `InitBinder` for all controller then there is way.

Comment: Because there is a date in HandlerInterceptor that has an effect on all the dynamic pages, and i need to format and validate this date. Also i have a written a Base Controller that provides InitBinder for all pages but i need a InitBinder to be registered on interceptor so that the date field that interceptor passes gets formatted and validated

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to register it in `HandlerInterceptor`. But if you want to register `@initBinder` for all of your controller you can use `@ControllerAdvice` which will apply `@initBinder` to all of your controller including BaseController.  [Here is the reference link how to do](http://keenformatics.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-create-global-initbinder-in-spring.html)

Comment: Yes i  have registered an initBinder for all controller in Base class but its no applicable to the Model returned through Interceptor class. So i was just wondering if we can have a separate Binder for Model class or is there any other solution to it.

Comment: P.S I cannot extend the base class through my interceptor as interceptor already extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter class